# In firefox, what is the difference between web console and browser console

Tags: javascript, firefox

What is the difference between web console and browser console in firefox 48?  They look rather close. Why two consoles?

web console

[image]
-- best place to run javascript

browser console
[image]

-- receive error message.
-- console.log output

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Mozilla

The **Browser Console** is like the Web Console, but applied to the whole browser rather than a single content tab.

So it logs the same sorts of information as the Web Console - network requests, JavaScript, CSS, and security errors and warnings, and messages explicitly logged by JavaScript code. However, rather than logging this information for a single content tab, it logs information for all content tabs, for add-ons, and for the browser's own code.

The **Web Console** on the other hand:

Logs information associated with a web page: network requests, JavaScript, CSS, security errors and warnings as well as error, warning and informational messages explicitly logged by JavaScript code running in the page context

Enables you to interact with a web page by executing JavaScript expressions in the context of the page

Sources:

[Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

[Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console)